# Applying css/style to a databind in a span element

Tags: html, css, knockout.js, data-binding

I am trying to apply css/style to a span element that uses a databind (from knockout) to grab a text name ("`config.title`"). My goal is to set a maximum pixel width of the string/text name that is grabbed and populated inside the span. Why wouldn't this work? Is there a better way to do this? Note: I've also tried using `style="textOverflow: ellipsis"` which didn't work either.

```
<span style="maxWidth: 20px" data-bind="text: config.title"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display` property with `<span>`.

I've made a snippet for demonstration, please have a look:

```css
.myspan {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="myspan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam facere, dignissimos! Nam porro suscipit, perspiciatis consectetur dolor explicabo voluptatem? Earum vel explicabo neque perspiciatis, dicta fugit dolorem dignissimos obcaecati quis.</span>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That totally worked. I think my problem was that I was only using one or two of the css attributes when I needed the correct combination for it to work properly. In particular, using `inline block` rather than just `block` for the display with the `overflow: hidden` seemed to be the ticket. Thanks.

Comment: Side note: `maxWidth` as I originally wrote does not work unless it's applied in javascript. `max-width` was the correct css attribute.

Comment: @jcbridwe Right. Its my pleasure!